# How can I prepend, append and join each item in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`myArr = [1,2,3,4,5]`

I would like to join but also prepend and append to each item

Result: `'$'1'^'|'$'2'^'|'$'3'^'|'$'4'^'|'$'5'^'|'$'6'^'`

I have tried this:

`console.log("$" + valArr.join("'|'") + "^");`

which results in:
`'$'1'|'2'^'`

I have tried: `valArr.map(i => "'$'" + i).join("|");` but this only appends.

Comment: So you can add `'$'` before the number but not `'^'` after it? Although it's the exact same thing you have to do/use?

Comment: Why first element 2 times? `'$'1'^'|'$'1'^'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First map the array and then join it,

```js
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((i) => `'$'${i}'^'`).join("|");
console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: Thank you, seeing it like this has made sense and really helped me learn